# anchor tag onlick event called automatically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have question regarding this jquery code block. What I am doing is, onclick on anchor tag, I am creating a anchor tag element and appending  it to 'currentFilters' div element.

While debugging through firebug, I can see that anchor element is getting added to the div, then jquery automatically calls onclick again so my anchor tag gets created twice.

Not sure how onclick event is triggered again automatically.

Also, on page load, this functionality works as expected.. But then I am doing ajax call to the server and creates more elements in the same page. then it doesnot work,,

```
$(document).ready(function() {                  
    $(".matchTypeCheckbox").click(function() {                  
        var parent = "parent_"  + $(this).attr('id');

        $('#' + parent).removeClass("").addClass("active");

        var newElement = 
        "<a tagid='"+ $(this).attr('id')
            + "' tagtype='mt' href='#' class='rTag'><span class='rTag'>X</span>"
            + $(this).text();
        +"</a>";

        $('.currentFilters').append(newElement);

    });                     
});
```

Comment: Try to add preventDefault in the function.

Comment: Is this all the  code you have? I think there might be something more to it.

Comment: @freedomn-m , sorry it is an anchor tag ,, not a checkbox

Comment: Have you got a jsfiddle of it not working?

Comment: it works fine on page load, only doesnt work after ajax call.. @freedomn-m

Comment: @Jkike - I tried that , no luck

Comment: @putvande - I have updated the post with ajax info which I missed initially

Answer (score 0):

> it works fine on page load, only doesnt work after ajax call

and

> But then I am doing ajax call to the server and creates more elements in the same page. then it does not work

When you call

```
$(".class").click(function() ...
```

it binds that anonymous/inline function to all elements with class "class" (in this example) - *that exist at the time the click() is called*.

This is why we use `$(function() {` (or `$(document).ready`, same thing), so that the `click` event is wired up after the DOM elements have been created and they already exist (to have the event attached).

If you then create new elements

```
$('.currentFilters').append(newElement);
```

the previous call on document ready has already been called so *is not applied to the new elements*.

There are two ways around this:

After calling append, also attach the click event handler (this works best with a separate function rather than anon/inline), something like (untested, ottomh) :

```
$(function() { 
  $(".class").click(clickHandler);
});

$('.currentFilters').append(newElement);
newElement.click(clickHandler)
```

or using event delegation, something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".class", clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: You are spot on the problem.. but I dont understand the solution that you have provide.. can you please explain – @freedomn-m

Comment: Imagine this - you want to paint your car from blue to red.  So you have a blue car, you paint it red.  Now, you buy another blue car - what colour is it?  It's still blue because you haven't painted it yet.  Same applies to event handlers.  You add an event handler to the existing element, then create a new element - there's no event handler on the new element yet.